# Matching two items in two different arrays

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I am using Jvectormap and have set an array as "areas" to group country together to be selected, which works. The next step is to give each country on the array its color. So i can define a different color to each country in each array.

UK may be pink in array 1 but green in array 2.

Also how do i assign to a click function:

```
$("#mp-cyprus-A").click(function(){
    $('#world-map').vectorMap('setSelectedRegions', ['areas[1]']);
});
```

Code for adding sets of area then add color set for each area:

```
  //MAP CONTROLS
$(function(){
  var areas = [];
  areas[0] = [];
  areas[2] = ["FR","BG","DK","HR","DE","BA","XK","CH","EE","IS","AL","IT","CZ","GB","IE","ES","ME","MD","RO","RS","MK","SK","SI","UA","SE","AT"];
  areas[2] = ["BE","FR","BG","DK","HR","DE","BA","HU","FI","BY","GR","NL","PT","NO","LV","LT","LU","XK","CH","EE","IS","AL","IT","CZ","GB","IE","ES","ME","MD","RO","RS","MK","SK","SI","UA","SE","AT"];
  areas[3] = ["CA"];
  areas[4] = ["CA"];
  areas[5] = ["CA"];
  areas[6] = ["CA"];

  function selectArea(code){
    var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
    areas.forEach(function(area) {
      if(area.indexOf(code)>-1) {
        mapObj.setSelectedRegions(area);
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  function clearAll(){
    var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
    mapObj.clearSelectedRegions();
  }
```

Part of code that doesnt work: Setting Array for each "areas". And apply it If the correseponding array betwwen "areas" and "areacolor".

```
   // Area Colors
      var areacolor = [];
        areacolor[0] = [
            {'BE': '#4E7387'},
            {'FR': '#333333'},
            {'BG': '#89AFBF'},
            {'DK': '#817F8E'},
            {'HR': '#344B5E'},
            {'FI': '#344B5E'},
            {'BY': '#344B5E'},
            {'GR': '#344B5E'}
        ]
        areacolor[1] = [
            {'BE': '#4E7387'},
            {'FR': '#333333'},
            {'BG': '#89AFBF'},
            {'DK': '#817F8E'},
            {'HR': '#344B5E'},
            {'FI': '#344B5E'},
            {'BY': '#344B5E'},
            {'GR': '#344B5E'}
        ]
        areacolor[2] = [
            {'BE': '#4E7387'},
            {'FR': '#333333'},
            {'BG': '#89AFBF'},
            {'DK': '#817F8E'},
            {'HR': '#344B5E'},
            {'FI': '#344B5E'},
            {'BY': '#344B5E'},
            {'GR': '#344B5E'}
        ]

        function selectArea(color){
            var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
            areascolor.forEach(function(color) {
              if(color.indexOf(color)>-1) {
                map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolor[0]);
                return;
              }
```

Vector map init:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    backgroundColor: '#5288F9',
    markersSelectable:'false',
    regionsSelectableOne: 'false',
    regionsSelectable: 'true',
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
          fill: "lightgrey"
        },
        selected: {
          fill: "darkseagreen"
        }
      },
    onRegionClick: function(e, code){
        clearAll();
        selectArea(code);
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Apply area filter

```
    (function () {
      // Collect the rest of the World
      var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
      var states = areas.join(",");
      for(var code in mapObj.regions) {
        if(mapObj.regions.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
          if(states.indexOf(code) == -1) {
            areas[0].push(code);
          }
        }
      }
    })();
```

});

UPDATE:

```
//MAP CONTROLS
var areacolors0  = {
    'BE': '#4E7387',
    'FR': '#333333',
    'BG': '#89AFBF',
    'DK': '#817F8E',
    'HR': '#344B5E',
    'FI': '#344B5E',
    'BY': '#344B5E',
    'GR': '#344B5E'
  };
  var areacolors1 = {
    'BE': '#000000',
    'FR': '#333333',
    'BG': '#000000',
    'DK': '#817F8E',
    'HR': '#000000',
    'FI': '#344B5E',
    'BY': '#344B5E',
    'GR': '#344B5E'
  };
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill',
        backgroundColor: '#5288F9',
        markersSelectable:'false',
        regionsSelectableOne: 'false',
        regionsSelectable: 'true',
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
              fill: "lightgrey"
            },
            selected: {
              fill: "darkseagreen"
            }
          },
          onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
            var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            var name = map.getRegionName(code);
            if(name == GR) {
            map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolors.GR);      
            }
            if(name == CH) {
                map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolors1.CH);         
                }


       },
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking to accomplish. I see your arrays, but what do you want to find in which array?

Comment: Also I see reference to `areascolor` in a function but I do not see where that is defined. I do see `areacolor`.

Comment: Think it would be better just to change the region colors when either a country is clicked or a button (linking to that country. there is no need to select the countrys as groups.

Comment: cant figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the complex nature of your data structure, you need to iterate deeper. So you have:

```
Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      key: value
    }
  ]
]
```

So to find the items that match a specific value, you need to iterate the initial array, iterate the array items in each element, and iterate each object in the matrix.

I prefer to use jQuery `$.each()`, it's the same idea as `.forEach()`.

```js
var areacolor = [];
areacolor[0] = [{
    'BE': '#4E7387'
  },
  {
    'FR': '#333333'
  },
  {
    'BG': '#89AFBF'
  },
  {
    'DK': '#817F8E'
  },
  {
    'HR': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'FI': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'BY': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'GR': '#344B5E'
  }
]
areacolor[1] = [{
    'BE': '#4E7387'
  },
  {
    'FR': '#333333'
  },
  {
    'BG': '#89AFBF'
  },
  {
    'DK': '#817F8E'
  },
  {
    'HR': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'FI': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'BY': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'GR': '#344B5E'
  }
]
areacolor[2] = [{
    'BE': '#4E7387'
  },
  {
    'FR': '#333333'
  },
  {
    'BG': '#89AFBF'
  },
  {
    'DK': '#817F8E'
  },
  {
    'HR': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'FI': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'BY': '#344B5E'
  },
  {
    'GR': '#344B5E'
  }
];

function selectArea(color) {
  //var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
  $.each(areacolor, function(k, ac) {
    console.log("Examine areacolor[" + k + "]");
    $.each(ac, function(i, area) {
      $.each(area, function(c, clr) {
        if (clr.indexOf(color) === 0) {
          console.log("Color Found: " + c + ", " + clr);
          //map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolor[0]);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

selectArea("#344B5E");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The console will show:

```
Examine areacolor[0]
Color Found: HR, #344B5E
Color Found: FI, #344B5E
Color Found: BY, #344B5E 
Color Found: GR, #344B5E
Examine areacolor[1]
Color Found: HR, #344B5E
Color Found: FI, #344B5E
Color Found: BY, #344B5E
Color Found: GR, #344B5E
Examine areacolor[2]
Color Found: HR, #344B5E
Color Found: FI, #344B5E
Color Found: BY, #344B5E
Color Found: GR, #344B5E
```

If you're simply assigning a color to a Country Code, it might be better to make a simply object:

```
var areacolors = {
  'BE': '#4E7387',
  'FR': '#333333',
  'BG': '#89AFBF',
  'DK': '#817F8E',
  'HR': '#344B5E',
  'FI': '#344B5E',
  'BY': '#344B5E',
  'GR': '#344B5E'
};
```

Then, if you know the Country Code, you can simply call it's index:

```
map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolors.GR); // Dot Notation preferred
```

Or

```
map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolor['GR']);
```

Or

```
var cc = "GR";
map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolor[cc]);
```

I am not familiar with this plugin you're using, so I cannot speak to how to set the proper values, I am just using your example to clarify my point.

Hope this helps.

**Update 1**

Your updated code appears correct. I would check Console for any alerts or Errors.

Also consider this:

```
var areacolors = {
  'BE': '#000000',
  'FR': '#333333',
  'BG': '#000000',
  'DK': '#817F8E',
  'HR': '#000000',
  'FI': '#344B5E',
  'BY': '#344B5E',
  'GR': '#344B5E'
};
```

And then:

```
onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
  var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
  var name = map.getRegionName(code);
  console.log("Name: " + name + ", Color: " + areacolors[name], map);
  map.series.regions[0].setValues(areacolors[name]);      
}
```

It appears all your colors are the same, so I do not see the benefit to multiple data sets. Just use one for all. Also the `console.log()` function can be very helpful in diagnosing issues.

Comment: I think the last option you suggested is best. just creat different arrays and call. i will have a play with that. Thanks you so much the above taught me something too. i will let you know how i get on. Thanks Twisty

Comment: Please check "UPDATE" above. i plugged it in, not functioning. is the script ok?

Comment: @happycoding I do not see `areacolors` defined anyplace. I think you mean `areacolors0`